# choosing AWS instance for Datastax OpsCenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm interested in using Datastax's OpsCenter Enterprise in AWS, and following the install instructions [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-to-create-a-datastax-enterprise-cluster-on-amazon-ec2-in-ten-minutes). I need some advice on how large of instance I need to run OpsCenter. I was considering a t2.medium instance, but concerned that is too small. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how many machines are you going to manage with OpsCenter, but t2.medium should be a good start. If you have a bunch of large-ish clusters (50-100+ nodes), consider switching to m3.large or m3.xlarge, depending on how much memory OpsCenter uses.